# Python script works in bash, but not when called from R via system

Tags: python, r, bash, shell

I use Ubuntu 16.04. I'm trying to run a simple python script from R. The script is

```
    import numpy as np
    x=1
    print(x)
```

and is written in a file named code.py. It works fine if I call it in bash via

```
    python3.5 code.py
```

However, when I call it in R via

```
    system("python3.5 code.py",intern=TRUE)
```

I get a message that says that numpy was not found. Any idea why there is this difference and how I can fix this?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

If I run a file with

```
     import sys 
     print(sys.path)
```

I get

```
     [1] "['/home/user/Desktop', '/usr/lib/python35.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.5', '/usr/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']"
```

if I run the file from R, and

```
    ['/home/user/Desktop', '/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python35.zip', '/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.5', '/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/plat-linux', '/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload', '/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages', '/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/Sphinx-1.4.1-py3.5.egg', '/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools-23.0.0-py3.5.egg']
```

if I run the file from the command line.

Comment: Add this to your program and see if it produces different output depending on the context: `import sys
print(sys.path)`

Comment: It says Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
    import numpy as np
ImportError: No module named 'numpy'
[1] "['/home/user/Desktop', '/usr/lib/python35.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.5', '/usr/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']"
attr(,"status")
[1] 1
Warning message:
running command 'python3.5 test.py' had status 1

Comment: Make a new python file with just those two lines. Run in both R and from the command line and compare the outputs.

Comment: I've updated my question with this info, otherwise it wouldn't fit here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have two versions of python3 on your computer: The system default (Ubuntu, I'm assuming), and the one you installed (Anaconda3).

When you run it from the command-line, you are using the Anaconda3 environment (which includes numpy and all the other anaconda modules). When you run it from R, it doesn't know to use the Anaconda environment, and so it just uses your default python paths (which doesn't include numpy).

To fix this, invoke your python script in R using the Anaconda python, not the system one:

`system("/home/user/anaconda3/bin/python3 code.py",intern=TRUE)`

Alternatively, you could add `/home/user/anaconda3/bin/` to your `PATH` environment variable in `~/.bashrc` so that it chooses anaconda over the system binary.

Comment: Thanks! I've used system("/home/user/anaconda3/bin/python3 code.py",intern=TRUE) and it works!